# How to detect collision in corona without physics engine?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

My problem is that two overlapping bodies are same.Like in tic tac toe where two cross symbols can overlap.How can i write code for this without physics collision in corona?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple collision detection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8521356/simple-collision-detection)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if you know their positions and sizes, you can simply check the range between position of first element and its position again but plus its size (in same axis). If in those scopes are presented position coordinates of second element (in all axis), then they are colliding.

Answer (score 1):

You can use various techniques like overlapping rectangles or simple geometry tests for circles. This tutorial should get you going:

https://coronalabs.com/blog/2013/07/23/tutorial-non-physics-collision-detection/